# How to connect to remote server in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ip, laravel-5.1

I am trying to connect to other db server in `laravel`, i changed the host and port in my `database.php` but it is not working can any one suggest help.

This is my **database.php**:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '192.168.1.6',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'ired4',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',

    ),
```

I am getting the following error:

> PDOException (2002)
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: Also change `username` and `password` ?

Comment: Make sure you've 3306 port open on given host with enough privileges.

Comment: Also, depending on laravel version, your `.ENV` file may be overriding `database.php`

Comment: It looks like your local server, use `127.0.0.1` as host

Comment: changed those also but no use

Comment: try to connect manually using `mysql` command line first.. if the host and credentials were correct it should be able to connect.